# How to change the "Recovery HD" partition to type "Apple_Boot"?

Tags: terminal, macos, partition

Typing in the terminal `diskutil list` gives me this...

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            499.1 GB   disk0s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS Recovery HD             629.1 MB   disk0s3
```

I try to change `disk0s3` to type "Apple_Boot", by using...

```
sudo asr adjust --target /dev/disk0s3 -settype "Apple_Boot"
```

But I keep getting the error...

```
asr: Volume adjustment failed: Operation not permitted
```

---

The partition isn't mounted. I have also tried the command as superuser.

Comment: Is `adjust` an new _verb_ in the version of `asr` that ships with OS X 10.11, as it is not one in OS X 10.10 and earlier?

Comment: What are you doing this? What's the goal?

Comment: @KhürtWilliams, Crimbo is probably trying to do it because it's supposed to show as: `Apple_Boot Recovery HD` **not** `Apple_HFS Recovery HD`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that normal "umount" command is not suitable here, especially if Recovery partition is on system hard disk (SSD/HDD).
I found working script on JAMFNation for that:

```
#!/bin/sh

RecoveryHDName="Recovery HD"
RecoveryHDID=/usr/sbin/diskutil list | grep "$RecoveryHDName" | awk 'END \{ print $NF }'\

/usr/sbin/diskutil unmount /dev/"$RecoveryHDID"
/usr/sbin/asr adjust -target /dev/"$RecoveryHDID" -settype Apple_Boot
/usr/sbin/diskutil info /dev/"$RecoveryHDID"*
```

The key is that you need to eject only this particular partition (you can do this from Finder also!)
and only then execute:
`sudo asr adjust --target /dev/diskNsM -settype "Apple_Boot"`
where you should replace N and M with your Disk and Partition number.

Apple Recovery partition is used as emergency tool. In case you cannot boot to your system, you at least can try to do repairs.

To access Recovery partition, reboot your Mac and press and hold Cmd+R during startup/power on.

Comment: Cheers for the answer! I am going to mark this as the correct answer - I cannot test it as the situation has past, but it has been over a year since another answer was provided

Comment: The idea is correct, but the script written in this way will does not work.

Right:
`#!/bin/sh

...
RecoveryHDID=$(/usr/sbin/diskutil list | grep "$RecoveryHDName" | /usr/bin/awk 'END { print $NF }')
...
sudo /usr/sbin/asr adjust -target /dev/"$RecoveryHDID" -settype Apple_Boot
/usr/sbin/diskutil info /dev/"$RecoveryHDID" | grep "Partition"`
P.S.
The prefixes "/usr/bin/" and "/usr/sbin/" can be omited, just like the last string.

Answer (score 1):

At first:

```
umount -f "/Volumes/Recovery HD"
```

Then:

```
sudo asr adjust --target /dev/disk0s3 -settype "Apple_Boot"
```

Comment: umount gives: umount: /Volumes/Recovery HD: not currently mounted,
thus asr still not able to execute.

Comment: Use “sudo” and everything will work properly: `umount -f "/ Volumes / Recovery HD"`