# Moving or creating Recovery Disk with dual internal SSD with RAID

Tags: macos, ssd, recovery, raid

I have removed my optical drive and installed a second SSD in its place.

To do this I partitioned the first SSD to hold macOS Sierra. The other partition was RAID0 with a second SSD. I seem to have my Recovery HD on disk1 instead of disk0. This causes my Recovery HD not to show up when the <kbd>option</kbd> key is pressed prior to startup.

YES, it is the <kbd>option</kbd> key for my 2010 MacBook, not <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> or anything else. This is verified. All that appears with option is the standard macOS

Here is my map with diskutil list:

[image: list]

But as you can see from the screenshot above, trying to use these solutions failed. Here is another screenshot showing that the answer of this forum failed.

[image: failed answered]

I would like to be able to use my Recovery HD because I need to change csrutil, which is not available for me to change via Internet Recovery nor Bootable USB.

Why do I want to change csrutil? So that I can modify my DVDPlayback file to read the DVD player I removed from the Mac, that is now in an external USB case.

I have already tried what's in the following:

- [How to change the "Recovery HD" partition to type "Apple_Boot"?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/217964/how-to-change-the-recovery-hd-partition-to-type-apple-boot?newreg=96b4b41732c143c4aaf1549d3caed81b%22)